# Actionscript specify Datatypes within Object

Tags: actionscript

```
var CustomerAge:int=65;
var CustomerName:String="Jane Doe";

//I want to convert the above to keep but I can't specify the datatype for each child object
var UserProfile:Object = new Object();
    UserProfile.CustomerAge:int=64;
    UserProfile.CustomerName:string="Jane Doe";

The below is works but I can't specify the datatype
var UserProfile:Object = new Object();
    UserProfile.CustomerAge=64;
    UserProfile.CustomerName="Jane Doe";
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: objects are dynamically typed. You should use a class. It's not that much extra work.

Answer (score 1):

What if you declare the elements with type when adding them to the object?

For instance:

```
var UserProfile:Object = new Object();
UserProfile.CustomerAge = new int(64);
UserProfile.CustomerName = new String("Jane Doe");
```

Hope it helps,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce types you should use a class not an Object.  Check out this tutorial: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html